# Installing Hudson on CentOS

Tags: hudson

Following the instructions here:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+using+RPM+repository

fails at the very first step:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/hudson.repo http://hudson-ci.org/redhat/hudson.repo
Connecting to hudson-ci.org|137.254.56.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-05-15 22:41:54 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Indeed opening http://hudson-ci.org/redhat/hudson.repo in a browser gives a 404. Can anyone help?

Comment: OK I've found that the Hudson documentation is indeed out of date and that URL is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins is the [fork from Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29#Hudson).  You should use Jenkins instead of Hudson, as that's where the community is right now.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins

CentOS repository info and RPMs are available at:

http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/

Once you have the repo configured, you should be able to do something like `yum install jenkins` and it will take care of it all.

Answer (score 2):

If that site is giving a 404, then there's a problem on Hudson-ci.org's end. Either the link was changed and the documentation wasn't updated, or they are experiencing availability issues.

What exactly do you think anyone here can do about it? Contact them.

Comment: Someone here can point out that the software has a new name and lives somewhere else now :)

Comment: "What exactly do you think anyone here can do about it? Contact them." - Are you here to help or berate? If the URL is incorrect perhaps you can tell me how to install it manually on CentOS.